# Custom action not called when ProgressDlg is displayed

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to update progress bar value on my custom ProgressDlg dialog but **my custom action is not called** when ProgressDlg appears.

Product.wxs

```
    <Product>
         <CustomAction Id="ShowTime" BinaryKey="myAction"  DllEntry="ShowTime" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />    
         <InstallUISequence>
              <!-- replace standart progress dialog with my custom -->
              <Show Dialog="DbProgressDlg" After="ProgressDlg" />      
         </InstallUISequence>    
         <InstallExecuteSequence>
              <!-- call? when? not clear -->
              <Custom Action="ShowTime" After="InstallInitialize"></Custom>
         </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
```

my custom dialog DbProgressDlg.wxs

```
<UI>
     <Dialog>
        <Control Id="InfoText" Type="Text" X="50" Y="130" Width="250"  Height="17">
          <Subscribe Event="ActionData" Attribute="Text" />
        </Control>
        <Control Id="MyProgressBar" Type="ProgressBar" X="50" Y="50"   Width="250" Height="20">
          <Subscribe Event="SetProgress" Attribute="Progress" />
        </Control>
     </Dialog>
     <ProgressText Action="ShowTime" Template="Doing Stuff: [1]" />
</UI>
```

My questions:

1. How to call my custom managed action?
2. Can use show standard ProgressDlg but split progress in two steps (my custom and then standard file copy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks funny but the problem was in file's section.

1. The action not called until your package without files
2. Your can use standard ProgressDlg and split progress in few steps. In custom action we can reset progress bar value and update it with our new